# CMake configuration alternatives in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have a CMake project in CLion. Under Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment I have two configurations - `Debug` and `Release`:

[image: a]

The `Configuration:` drop-down has the standard CMake build types (Default, Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo, MinSizeRel) and you can type your own.

I want to have two different configurations - both `Release` but with different CMake options. I can do that, but they both end up being called `Release`. If I change the `Configuration` to something like `Release Engineering` then CLion passes `"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release Engineering"` to CMake which obviously isn't what I want.

Even if I *do* make a `Release Engineering` config like this:

[image: b]

Then it shows up in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog as `Release`, and you can't really select it - they're obviously indexed by value rather than position so it just uses the first `Release` entry.

[image: c]

Is there any way around this annoyance?

*Edit:* Also if I make a new RelWithDebInfo configuration it doesn't show up at all in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh seems to be a flaw of CLion:

- [CLion doesn't allow having several CMake configurations with the same name](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8466)
- [Consider multiple CMake build profiles to support cross-compilation](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2714) (better explained in [Feature request: CMake "profiles" (better control of CMake configuration)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10345))

The original bug report is from March 2015 so I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a *Build type* with the name `Release Engineering`? Space is often used in CMake as separator between arguments. Have you tried creating a *Build type* without space, e.g. `ReleaseEngineering`?

Comment: It does correctly handle spaces, i.e. `"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release Engineering"` is passed. However that isn't what I want, and if you use something like `ReleaseEngineering` it doesn't show up in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog at all. CLion is just broken here.